# Identifying all numbers in a group chat using the Twilio API

Tags: node.js, express, sms, twilio

I'm working on an SMS service, that is intended to be used in a group text.

For example, a group text with three members, myself, my boss, and the Twilio number.

I want my service, which is included in the above group chat, to "know" that my boss and I are chatting together. Basically, I want to deduce that there is some correlation between my boss and his cell phone number, and me and my cell phone number.

I'm using Node.js, Express and the [Twilio npm module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you would have to buy multiple Twilio numbers, one for each participant, or at least one for each participant that should be individually targeted. This way the Twilio API will POST back to your application the received info, including the `From` and `To`. You can then write your own logic on how to handle the messages based on the received information.

[image]

I guess you could simply forward the same SMS to the rest of the group that might not have Twilio numbers. You would store the info in a database.

Check the [Twilio Help Center page](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio), they also have some information on scaling.

There are also a few examples that might help (not for node.js though):

- for ASP.NET: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/rewind-build-a-group-messaging-application-with-asp-net-mvc.html
- for Meteor: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/building-a-group-messaging-app-with-meteor-mongodb-and-twilio.html